# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python

Must I upgrade the system's python from 3.7 to 3.9.9 or is it something else?

`blender -b -E CYCLES -f 1`

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
Blender 3.0.0 (hash f1cca3055776 built 2021-12-03 00:34:54)
BLT_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'droidsans.ttf', will not be able to display text
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = '/usr/lib/python3.7'
  program name = '/usr/local/bin/blender'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 0
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python/lib/python39.zip',
    '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python/lib/python3.9',
    '/home/sybren/buildbot-builder/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/build_deps/deps/Release/python/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Internal error initializing Python!
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f6f5cb0f200 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Comment: You need at least python V3.9 for Blender 2.93+

Comment: Will gladly marks as answer. Yet, the problems [ensue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247933/headless-background-blender-not-starting-with-many-python-errors) upon installing V.3.9

Answer (score 0):

Unlucky git pull?

I ran into this compiling Blender 3.1.

```
strace ./bin/blender
```

showed me that it was looking for python3.10 but there was no python3.10 found here:

```
cd build_linux_full    
ls bin/3.1/python/bin/
```

but there is here:

```
ls ../lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/bin
```

I must've done my update at the wrong time?  I went back up to cd ../blender and did a make update and built again and the problem was solved...  now I've got Blender 3.2 with python 3.10 found here:

```
ls bin/3.2/python/bin/
```